# CookiesEu gem to add cookie consent doesn't disappear after pressing ok

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rubygems

So I've added CookiesEu gem to my application to add cookie consent. But the problem is the text: `Cookies help us deliver our services. By using our services, you agree to our use of cookies.  OK  Learn more` stays in sight after pressing the `OK` button. Whereas I want it to disappear after pressing `OK`.

in the documentation it says: `This gem uses a cookie called cookie_eu_consented to track whether a user has accepted the cookie notice and whether it needs to be shown again or not.` But the cookie notice is shown even after accepting the cookie.

p.s. I put the `= render 'cookies_eu/consent_banner', link: '/cookies'` in the footer

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Rails 6 or above JavaScript is now delivered using webpacker. This breaks the current file structure and causes the JavaScript that would normally deal with the 'Ok' button to fail.

You can find a solution below:

To make this work with Webpacker. Your JavaScript code must be imported as a webpack dependency instead of embedding JS in  tags in the view.

Step one:

Make sure the following tags are in your layout:

```
   <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
   <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

Second:

Just as in the README The banner HTML should be in your layout/view, i.e., `<div id="cookies-eu-banner" style="display: none;">...</div>`

Third:

Add a JS file for initializing the banner somewhere in app/javascript/, (but not in app/javascript/packs), like app/javascript/src/add-banner.js. Here, you'll import the library (and CSS if you want) and initialize it when the DOM content has loaded:

```
// app/javascript/src/add-eu-banner.js

import CookiesEuBanner from 'cookies-eu-banner'
import 'cookies-eu-banner/css/cookies-eu-banner.default.css'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  new CookiesEuBanner(() => {
    console.log('Cookies EU Banner accepted');
  })
})
```

Finally:

Add that file as a webpack dependency by adding an import statement in the "application.js" pack file:

```
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import '../src/add-eu-banner'
```

If you are using a version of Rails lower than 6 I suggest posting your code up so people can take a deeper look into your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that

```
//= require cookies_eu
```

was added to your application.js after you ran
`bundle exec rails g cookies_eu:install`